# Did "Where Is Everybody?" have any influence on multi-person crews?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, crew-size

The pilot episode of *The Twilight Zone* entitled "Where Is Everybody?" portrays a lone astronaut going crazy due to long-term isolation and lonliness.  At the end of the episode, the general in charge of the experiment claims

> *You see, we can feed the stomach with concentrates. We can supply microfilm for reading, recreation - even movies of a sort. We can pump oxygen in and waste material out. But there's one thing we can't simulate that's a very basic need. Man's hunger for companionship. The barrier of loneliness - that's one thing we haven't licked yet.*

The episode aired October 2, 1959, almost two years before Yuri Gagarin's first manned spaceflight on April 12, 1961.  Through 1963, both Soviet and American programs sent only single-person crews into space.  Starting with Voskhod 1 in 1964, the Soviets flew multi-person crews (with a few early exceptions).  The American program has exclusively flown multi-person crews, starting with Gemini 4 in 1965.

*Did this Twilight Zone episode have any influence on this trend toward multi-person crews?*  Please support your answer with a relevant source of that era.

Comment: I'm looking forward to reading some unearthed report to Congress or the Politburo saying "After thorough review of all relevant episodes of *The Twilight Zone*, space agency administrators have concluded that..." ;-)

Comment: It's a bit silly to assume a TV show can make a major psychological breakthrough. IOW the problems of long-term isolation were well known by then.

Comment: Let me be clear that I personally doubt there was such a connection.  However, I can expect some reporter at the time asking an official about the connection, and the official denying it.  That's what the question is asking about.